# jQuery: Button click triggers multiple times

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

On my site I have multiple buttons and every button is loaded on the site twice through ajax from the same file.

Though my problem is that this event fires twice if the same button is loaded twice. Though it works fine if only one of the buttons is loaded.

My code:

index.php

```
<div id="firstButtonContainer">
</div>

<div id="secondButtonContainer">
</div>

<script>

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
    script.onload = function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/firstButtonContainer.php',
            success: function(msg) {
                jQuery('#firstButtonContainer').html(msg);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/secondButtonContainer.php',
            success: function(msg) {
                jQuery('#secondButtonContainer').html(msg);
            }
        });

    };document.body.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

buttons.php

```
<button class="testbutton">Button1</button>
<button class="testbutton">Button2</button>
<button class="testbutton">Button3</button>
<button class="testbutton">Button4</button>

<script>

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
script.onload = function(){



$(".testbutton").on("click", function(event){
  alert("this should only appear once");
});


};document.body.appendChild(script);

</script>
```

firstButtonContainer.php

```
<div id="buttons">
</div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/buttons.php',
    success: function(msg) {
        jQuery('#buttons').html(msg);
    }
});
</script>
```

secondButtonContainer.php

```
<div id="buttonsTwo">
</div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/test/buttons.php',
    success: function(msg) {
        jQuery('#buttonsTwo').html(msg);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: why are you loading them twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".testbutton").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("this should only appear once");
});
```

**OR**

```
$(".testbutton").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("this should only appear once");
});
```

[**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

[**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

**Comment Response**

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test/firstButtonContainer.php',
            success: function(msg) {
                jQuery('#firstButtonContainer').html(msg);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'test/secondButtonContainer.php',
            success: function(msg) {
                jQuery('#secondButtonContainer').html(msg);
            }
        });

        $(".testbutton").live("click", function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("this should only appear once");
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="firstButtonContainer">
</div>

<div id="secondButtonContainer">
</div>
```

**buttons.php**

```
<button class="testbutton">Button1</button>
<button class="testbutton">Button2</button>
<button class="testbutton">Button3</button>
<button class="testbutton">Button4</button>
```

Comment: stopPropogation wont work in IE < 9 - that can be fixed with cancelBubble

Comment: @djjjuk then OP could just use the DOM click event and handle everything from there.

Comment: problem is inside first and second button container php file because from both files you are calling url: '/test/buttons.php' and in button.php file you assigning click event so event is assigning twice and hence its loading for two time... so all you need to do is clear first event n then add it again...

Comment: unbinding click event might also help $("#someid").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){...

Comment: @DipeshParmar I tried moving `$(".testbutton").on("click", function(event){...` to index.php but now, none of them triggers. Note that I should be able to click a button multiple times and it should appear one message per click.

Comment: Works now, thanks. Though I still use `script.onload = function(){...` But replaced the content in the function with your code.

Comment: excellent its doesn't matter if you use script.onload i just gave standard way of jQuery code... +1 for you..

Comment: I had not heard about `.live` before so I looked it up. In the [documentations](http://api.jquery.com/live/) it says that you should use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live` if you are using jQuery 1.7.0 or above. So the code should look like this `$(document).on("click", ".vote", function(){...`

Comment: Also, I don't seem to need `event.preventDefault();`, it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are not firing the ajax calls properly, they should all have unique id's (i.e. testbutton1, testbutton2, etc...) and really be having onclick triggers in jQuery like so:

```
$("#testbutton1").click(function(){
  // do ajax call here for button1           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit odd to me!
That happens because every time you fetch HTML through AJAX call you bind new event handler to all buttons because of css class selector you use. To resolve this problem I have two suggestions:

1- use a bit more complecated PHP code to generate a random ( or some pattern ) ID for each button and just use that unique IDs to bind new event.

```
<?php
$id = "btn_id_" . rand (100,1000);
?>
<buttom class='whatever' id='<?php echo $id; ?>'>

$("#<?php echo $id; ?>").on("click", function(event){
  alert("this should only appear once");
});
```

2- IF you do not like above solution just use jQuery live trigger out side your AJAX requets:

a. remove your onload script from buttons.php

b. add the following javascript code to your index.php

```
<script>
(".testbutton").live ( 'click', function () {
   alert ( "This happens only once!" );
});
</script>
```

And every thing should be fine. 
jQuery live event takes care of every newly added element that selector and attaches event handler to it and gurantees that happens only once.

**My personal choose is item no. 1**

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you bind the same event more than once, each bind count, 
so, if this is the reason, you can solve it in this way:

```
// unbind the same event, before you bind it,
$("xxx").unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```